# how to install or get php 5.5.9 COM extention

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.5.9. In my php.ini file, the COM extension is not available. How do I add the COM extension?

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

In my php file it shows the below error:

```
include(COM.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: That error is nothing to do with the extension, it's because you're calling `include('COM.php');` and COM.php doesn't exist.

Comment: it's a default class in php. how to use that COM class in PHP 5.5.9?

Comment: `include` is for files. If you've installed the extension correctly, you don't need to do `include` anything to have the class defined. Check things like `phpinfo()` to see if the extension is properly loaded.